# Java Play 2.5 missing ebean

Tags: java, eclipse, model, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm getting into learning the Play Framework but I'm struggling with importing `import play.db.ebean.Model;`. It can't find it. I've done some searching and found out that I need to add it in the `build.sbt` which I've done like the following:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

And also in the `plugins.sbt` the following way:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

I've also added the following to `application.conf`:

```
ebean.default="models.*"
```

And while I was there, I established the mysql connection too (but irrelevant for this).

After that I tried creating my User class with extending the Model:

```
public class User extends Model {

}
```

But it doesn't even suggest the `import play.db.ebean.Model;` and like I said in the start, adding it manually just provides an error that it cannot be resolved.

I've tried `activator clean`and `activator compile` and to clean the **Eclipse** project with no success. Any ideas what I missed?

Comment: Have you regenerated the eclipse project files?  Try `activator eclipse` to regenerate them, and then maybe restart your eclipse instance to reload the project files (probably a way of doing this without restarting).

Comment: I will give it a try but I suspect it won't work still since the project doesn't even compile with the changes to build.sbt and plugins.sbt.

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct import statement for Ebean for Play 2.4.x and 2.5.x is:

`import com.avaje.ebean.Model;`

---

Your model class should look like this:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.*;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

@Entity
public class Task extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    ...
}
```